# When trying change symbol in char* string got an Segmentation fault error

Tags: c, string

When I execute the next code it runs fine

```
// Example program
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *dbString = strdup("172.0.0.1:5000");
  char *port = strchr(dbString, ':');
  printf("port = %s\n", port);
  if (port)
    *port++ = '\0';
  printf("port = %s\n", port);
  return 0;
}
```

But if I execute the next code I got an error.

```
// Example program
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *port = (char*) ":5000";
  printf("port = %s\n", port);
  if (port)
    *port++ = '\0';
  printf("port = %s\n", port);
  return 0;
}
```

Could you explain to me the reason for the error?

Comment: The question title doesn't qui match the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second example, `":5000"` is a string literal. The compiler places the string literal in a readonly memory section. You are trying to change that string which is ilegal.

Comment: `strdup` malloc a new memory

Comment: @张浩杰 In the first example, yes. In the second example there's is no `strdup`.